# div scale transform problems

Tags: javascript, html, css, gwt

I am using a scale transform on a div so that I can use child elements with set positions and sizes and still scale to fill the screen. I am writing in GWT 2.7 and am having problems changing element visibility in Chrome and Safari (webkit bug?) on a Mac. Here's an example:

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
 <style>
 #container { position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 30px; width: 576px; height: 456px; overflow: hidden; background-color: cyan; }
 #backCanvas { position: absolute; left: 44px; top: 260px; }
 #frontCanvas { position: absolute; left: 240px; top: 397px; }
 
 .scaled
 {
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0; /* IE 9 */
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
 
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0; /* Safari 8 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
 
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: scale(1.2);
 }
 </style>
</head>

<body onload="initCanvas()">
 <div id="container" class="">
  <canvas id="backCanvas" tabindex="-1" width="490" height="158"></canvas>
  <canvas id="frontCanvas" tabindex="-1" width="87" height="31"></canvas>
 
  <button onclick="showScaled(false)">Unscaled</button>
  <button onclick="showScaled(true)">Scale transform</button>
  <button onclick="showElement('frontCanvas',false)">Hide canvas</button>
  <button onclick="showElement('frontCanvas',true)">Show canvas</button>
 </div>
 
 <script>
  function initCanvas()
  {
   fillCanvas(document.getElementById("backCanvas"), "green");
   fillCanvas(document.getElementById("frontCanvas"), "red");
  }
  
  function fillCanvas(canvas, color)
  {
   var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
   context.fillStyle = color;
   context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }
  
  function showScaled(scaled)
  {
   document.getElementById("container").className = scaled ? "scaled" : "";
  }
  
  function showElement(element, show)
  {
   // none of these work when scaled
   document.getElementById(element).style.display = show ? null : "none";
//   document.getElementById(element).style.visibility = show ? "visible" : "hidden";
//   document.getElementById(element).style.zIndex = show ? "100" : "-100";
//    document.getElementById(element).style.left = show ? "240px" : "-1000px";
  }
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It works in Chrome on my Mac.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for trying. For me, I get the green canvas in front of the red canvas, which should never happen. I have not found a fix yet. Maybe I can coerce the container to relayout/redraw?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with overflow:hidden. I included that in the container because that's what GWT does. So, I removed overflow from the container and added overflow:hidden to the body. This works for my app because I scale to fit the window. There may be some clipping problems with the container, but now the draw order works correctly.

This is a webKit bug that is in the process of being fixed.